# Reset rolling calculation when category changes in DF

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df that looks like this:

```py
        Category    Product     Location    Date formatted  Volume
    0   A           TYPE_B      Central     2019-04-01      13.0
    1   A           TYPE_B      Central     2019-05-01      13.0
    2   A           TYPE_B      Central     2019-06-01      12.0
    3   A           TYPE_B      Central     2019-07-01      14.0
    4   A           TYPE_B      Central     2019-08-01      14.0
    5   A           TYPE_B      Central     2019-09-01      13.0
    6   A           TYPE_B      Central     2019-10-01      14.0
    7   A           TYPE_B      Central     2019-11-01      13.0
    8   A           TYPE_B      Central     2019-12-01      13.0
    9   A           TYPE_B      Central     2020-01-01      13.0
    10  A           TYPE_B      Central     2020-02-01      13.0
    11  A           TYPE_B      Central     2020-03-01      15.0
    12  A           TYPE_B      East        2019-04-01      21.0
    13  A           TYPE_B      East        2019-05-01      20.0
    14  A           TYPE_B      East        2019-06-01      18.0
    15  A           TYPE_B      East        2019-07-01      21.0
    16  A           TYPE_B      East        2019-08-01      22.0
    17  A           TYPE_B      East        2019-09-01      19.0
    18  A           TYPE_B      East        2019-10-01      20.0
    19  A           TYPE_B      East        2019-11-01      20.0
    20  A           TYPE_B      East        2019-12-01      19.0
    21  A           TYPE_B      East        2020-01-01      20.0
    22  A           TYPE_B      East        2020-02-01      20.0
    23  A           TYPE_B      East        2020-03-01      27.0
```

I'm trying to calculate the rolling 3 month volume for each location from the start ("2019-04-01") and end ("2020-03-01) time frames for the data, so far I am using the following code:

```py
df['Rolling_3_'] = df.loc.iloc[:,4].rolling(window=4).mean()
```

This gives me my rolling 3 month mean for the entire dataframe. However, does anyone know how I can restart the rolling month calculation so that when it reaches another "Location" such as "East" it will calculate the rolling 3 months average for that location and move on to the next location, restarting the calculation? In essence calculating the rolling 3 months for the entire dataset, but with the values being applicable to the location. Is there a way I could possibly do this with the date itself? such as when "2019-04-01" appears again the calculation restarts.

Many thanks for any help/suggestions in advance!

Kind regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a groupby:

```
df.groupby(['Category','Product','Location']).Volume.rolling(3).mean()
```

gives you:

```
Category  Product  Location    
A         TYPE_B   Central   0           NaN
                             1           NaN
                             2     12.666667
                             3     13.000000
                             4     13.333333
                             5     13.666667
                             6     13.666667
                             7     13.333333
                             8     13.333333
                             9     13.000000
                             10    13.000000
                             11    13.666667
                   East      12          NaN
                             13          NaN
                             14    19.666667
                             15    19.666667
                             16    20.333333
                             17    20.666667
                             18    20.333333
                             19    19.666667
                             20    19.666667
                             21    19.666667
                             22    19.666667
                             23    22.333333
Name: Volume, dtype: float64
```

To get this into your dataframe, you need to pass the underlying numpy array due to the difference of index

```
# notice `values` at the end
df['rolling_mean'] = df.groupby(['Category','Product','Location']).Volume.rolling(3).mean().values
```

Comment: When add the date column to the df I get NaN, is there anyway I can keep the date column? Just because I will need it for analysis later down the road.

Seems to work really well otherwise, thank you!